# Count # of related lookup records with rollup helper

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have a use case where I need to count the number of records with a specific "status" that lookup to the opportunity.  I thought rollup helper would be able to handle this, but there is no unquie ID listed in rollup helpers interface (the record ID would be perfect).

[image]

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The expression `dsfs_docusign_status__c > dsfs__Completed_Age__c` defines which child records are going to be filtered in the rollup. Then, select the 'Count' radio button that will count the filtered children. No ID required.  'COUNT' will count the IDs of the children matching the filter

Comment: @cropredy I just selected dsfs__Completed_Age__c as an arbitrary value.  Are you saying it doesn't matter what field I select here if I just want a count?

Comment: I'm not familiar with RollupHelper but if the UI is like SFDC Rollup Summary fields then selecting Count without a filter should work.  If not, define a filter that always returns true

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this question on my lunch break while researching something unrelated, I'm one of the developers on the Rollup Helper team, figured I may as well chime in while I'm here.

My recommendation is to use the "deleted" field as the source field for your rollup, using a 'count' rollup to sum the number of records, you'll get a tally for all existing records. Then you can make a filter on the rollup to tally up only the results that have the correct 'status' set.

If you happen to have the paid version with the real time enabled, doing it this way has the advantage of guaranteeing that the real time updates always keep the tally accurate after your initial batch run, since the rollups only recalculate if a change to a relevant field was made on a child record change, picking "deleted" as the source field eliminates the small chance of overlooking some edge case that'll cause the rollup not to fire occasionally, save you some headache.

Hope it helps, and good luck!

Comment: Is there any trick to getting relations to be available for rollup?  I have multiple relations on an object but only one of them is showing as available in the rollup field config :/